# Qt(C++)で日本語のJSONが読めない

Tags: c++, json, qt, qt-creator

Jsonファイルをリードする関数を作っているのですが
同じファイルをLinuxとWindowsでリードしたところ、
Windows側はJsonファイル内に日本語があるとリードできませんでした
全て英数字のJsonファイルならLinuxでもWindowsでも問題なくリードできるのですが
QtのWindows版は日本語込みのJsonはリードする方法は無いでしょうか
以下のソースなのですが・・・

```
    //QJson::Parser
    QFile loadfile(_filename);
    if(loadfile.open(QFile::ReadOnly) == false){
        _errstring = loadfile.errorString();
        return false;
    }
    //ファイルオープン成功
    QTextStream in(&loadfile);
    QJsonDocument   jDoc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(in.readAll().toUtf8());  //●jDocに日本語があるとデータが入ってこない
```

Windows側はMinGW64bitを使用しています

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSONファイルであれば、`QTextStream`を介さずに、直接`QFile`から読み出してもよいと思います。

```
    //QJson::Parser
    QFile loadfile(_filename);
    if(loadfile.open(QFile::ReadOnly) == false){
        _errstring = loadfile.errorString();
        return false;
    }
    //ファイルオープン成功
    QJsonDocument   jDoc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(loadfile.readAll());
```

この場合、`loadfile.readAll()`で`QByteArray`の型でファイルデータが返ってくるので、
`QJSonDocument::fromJson(const QByteArray &json, QJsonParseError *error = Q_NULLPTR)`
のメソッドで処理できると思います。

＃`readAll()`メソッドは、`QFile`の継承元の`QIODevice`クラスのメソッドです。(参考: [`QIODevice`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html))

Comment: ありがとうございます。
`````
//QJson::Parser
QFile loadfile(_filename);
if(loadfile.open(QFile::ReadOnly) == false){
    _errstring = loadfile.errorString();
    return false;
}
//ファイルオープン成功
QJsonDocument   jDoc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(loadfile.readAll()); //バイト配列でファイルリード
QJsonObject     jObj = jDoc.object();        //JSONのオブジェクトとして変換
foreach (QString key , jObj.keys()) {
    if(key == "XXXXX"){
                 //振り分け色々
    }
}
`````
こんな感じでいけました

Answer (score 0):

おそらくデフォルトのCodecがシフトJISになっているのでしょう。
`QTextStream in(&loadfile);`の直後、`QJsonDocument   jDoc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(in.readAll().toUtf8());`の前に`in.setCodec("UTF-8");`を挿入すれば良いと思われます。

[void QTextStream::setCodec(const char *codecName)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#setCodec-1)

> Sets the codec for this stream to the QTextCodec for the encoding specified by codecName. Common values for codecName include "ISO 8859-1", "UTF-8", and "UTF-16". If the encoding isn't recognized, nothing happens.
> Example:
>
> ```
> QTextStream out(&file);
> out.setCodec("UTF-8");
> ```

[QTextStreamで文字コードを変換するメモ](http://see-ku.com/wiki/wiki.cgi?page=QTextStream%A4%C7%CA%B8%BB%FA%A5%B3%A1%BC%A5%C9%A4%F2%CA%D1%B4%B9%A4%B9%A4%EB%A5%E1%A5%E2)

> QTextStreamには、文字コードや改行コードを変換しながらテキストを入出力してくれる機能があるらしい。これは、どれぐらい使えるものなのか？　さくっと実験してみたのでメモ。
> ...
> 機種ごとの相違点はこんな感じ
>
> - Windowsでは『System』でShift JISに対応

[QTextStream Class Detailed Description](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#details)

> Internally, QTextStream uses a Unicode based buffer, and QTextCodec is used by QTextStream to automatically support different character sets. **By default, QTextCodec::codecForLocale() is used** for reading and writing, but you can also set the codec by calling setCodec().

[QTextCodec *QTextCodec::codecForLocale()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcodec.html#codecForLocale)

> Returns a pointer to the codec most suitable for this locale.
> The codec will be retrieved from ICU where that backend is in use, otherwise it may be obtained from an OS-specific API. **In the latter case, the codec's name may be "System"**.

Comment: すいません・・・in.setCodeで試してみたのですが上手く行きませんでした
何かやり方を間違ったのかもしれないのですが、とりあえず今回は別の方の方で上手く行ったのでそちらでこの質問は締めたいと思います
。説明文を見てると上手く行きそうなのですが・・・

Comment: なるほど、まあ説明が不足しているのかもしれませんね。書かれていない仕様とかは勘弁してほしいところですが。